# Difference between S3GeoTiffReader and GeoTiffReader?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, amazon-s3

What's the difference between [S3GeoTiffReader](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/s3-geotiff/src/main/java/org/geotools/s3/geotiff/S3GeoTiffFormat.java) and [GeoTiffReader](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/geotiff/src/main/java/org/geotools/gce/geotiff/GeoTiffFormat.java) provided by Geotools library?
I need to process a GeoTiff image retrieved from AWS S3 bucket.

Comment: in which library?

Comment: Geotools is the library

Comment: you need to edit the question to make it appear in the reopen queue